# No such value error in JSON

Tags: android

In my application my back end is PHP,i'm getting values in the form of **JSON**,i'm hitting some xyz url and it gives some JSON objects for example say 10 Json objects(ie. from 0 to 10 Json objects),and i'm having load_more button when user pressed that button then same xyz url will be hit and get another 10 objects(ie. from 10 to 20 Json objects),
now the problem is for the first time it takes all the values in a single Json object but if i hit second time it not taking all the values in a single Json object
even though the values is available,and it saying **No such values found**

Here is my Asynctask

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Gropinion_Questions.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        try {
            pDialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return Utils.getJSONString(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        if (null == result || result.length() == 0) {
            showToast("No data found from web!!!");
            Gropinion_Questions.this.finish();
        } else {

            // get JSON result and give to JsonObject
            try {
                JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(result);
                System.out.println("result........."+result);

                JSONArray    jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray(ARRAY_NAME);

                System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@ jsonArray @@@@@@@@@@@ "+jsonArray.length());

                Singleton.jsonArray = jsonArray;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                    JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    objItem = new QuestionsObject();

                    objItem.setDbcsFacebookProfile(objJson.optString(dbcsFacebookProfile));

                    objItem.setAvatar_img(objJson.optString(Avatar_image));

                    objItem.setVotebar(objJson.optString(percentagenumber));

                    objItem.setProfile_picture_value(objJson.optString(PROFILE_PIC_VALUE));

                    objItem.setId(objJson.optString(ID));
                    objItem.setTitle(objJson.optString(TITLE));
                    objItem.setNick_name(objJson.optString(NICKNAME));
                    objItem.setQues_type(objJson.optString(QUESTIONTYPE));
                    objItem.setCategories(objJson.getString(CATEGORIES));
                    objItem.setSubcatid(objJson.getString(SUBCATID));
                    objItem.setTotal_vote(objJson.getString(TV));

                    arrayOfList.add(objItem);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            setAdapterToListview();

            if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                try {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    pDialog = null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my first Json response

```
 {
    "questions": [
        {
            "ID": "4260",
            "unique_que": "N2pJS",
            "Title": "Which actress looks more beautiful?",
            "NickName": "shon17",
            "Avatar": "0",
            "dbcsFacebookProfile": "0",
            "QuestionType": "1",
            "Categories": "Shopping & Fashion",
            "SubCategoryID": "5",
            "Hash": "531ff16d876fe",
            "Ext": "jpg",
            "avragequestionrate": "0",
            "progressBar": "0, 0, 0, 0",
            "TotalVote": "0",
            "productImage": "531ff16d876fe.jpg,531ff16d89841.jpg,,",
            "description": "Katrina,kareena,,",
            "productThumbImage": "531ff16d876fe_thumb_75_75.png,531ff16d89841_thumb_75_75.png,,",
            "avatarImage": "1258602873_avatar_75_75.jpg",
            "Default_image_status": "1",
            "voteBar": "0, 531ff16d876fe.jpg, 531ff16d876fe_thumb_75_75.png"
        }
```

Here is my second Json response

```
 {
    "questions": [
        {
            "ID": "4232",
            "unique_que": "b6h4a",
            "Title": "which actress do u like more?",
            "NickName": "shon17",
            "Avatar": "0",
            "dbcsFacebookProfile": "0",
            "QuestionType": "1",
            "Categories": "Shopping & Fashion",
            "SubCategoryID": "5",
            "Hash": "531eb4fdc0dd3",
            "Ext": "jpg",
            "avragequestionrate": "0",
            "progressBar": "33, 1, 66, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3",
            "TotalVote": "3",
            "productImage": "531eb4fdc0dd3.jpg,531eb4fdc2c4c.jpg,,",
            "description": "katrina,deepika,,"
        }
```

This is how i'm getting as a response but when i hit this in browser that time it showing all the fields for load_more but in response it not fetching

I made change from getstring to optstring now it saying different exceotion

Here is my exeption

```
   03-12 06:09:03.705: W/System.err(1408): org.json.JSONException: Index 7 out of range [0..7)
03-12 06:09:03.705: W/System.err(1408):     at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:263)
03-12 06:09:03.705: W/System.err(1408):     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:480)
03-12 06:09:03.705: W/System.err(1408):     at com.android.groupinion.Gropinion_Questions$MyTask.onPostExecute(Gropinion_Questions.java:1041)
03-12 06:09:03.705: W/System.err(1408):     at com.android.groupinion.Gropinion_Questions$MyTask.onPostExecute(Gropinion_Questions.java:1)
03-12 06:09:03.705: W/System.err(1408):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-12 06:09:03.705: W/System.err(1408):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-12 06:09:03.705: W/System.err(1408):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-12 06:09:03.705: W/System.err(1408):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 06:09:03.705: W/System.err(1408):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 06:09:03.705: W/System.err(1408):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-12 06:09:03.705: W/System.err(1408):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 06:09:03.705: W/System.err(1408):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-12 06:09:03.705: W/System.err(1408):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-12 06:09:03.705: W/System.err(1408):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-12 06:09:03.705: W/System.err(1408):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post your json how is it look like ? And also put your logcat error.

Comment: Put you android logcat as i think your issue is only with json object because in your first response it contain key `voteBar` while in second it does not contain so your problem is that.

Comment: As your problem is `No such value error in JSON` it because your first time response contain all key which you try to fetch which in second time one of key pair value is missing from that Json Object so you will get `'No such value error in JSON'`.To avoid such time you need to check `objJson.has("Youkey")` for each key or may be key which may come or may not come ,if your Json Object contain key then you can go to use `getString();`

Comment: Ya that is absolutely correct but when i hit the url in browser, it showing all the values but in code it not fetching,

Comment: if you compare both the response you can find the last four parameters are not available in second response

Comment: Now my problem is that only,why it not coming for the second time even though all are same

Comment: So you mean to say that second time when you hit url and in `onPostExecute(String result)` it response miss four last parameter.I advice to try to write response in txt file then check it.Because android log have some limit to show response event they are complete.

Comment: Yaeh i clicked like that also it provide the same thing

Comment: then why you have use 10 as constant value for fetching json Array .Are you sure that you r second time response contain more then `10` questions .

Comment: Can you give me this line code from your this java file Gropinion_Questions.java:1041<--.

Comment: instead of using 10 use jsonArray.lenth() just for checking, that might work for you.

Comment: 1041 line code : JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

Comment: i changed with JsonArray.length() then also the same problem,i'm sure because of this missing arguments only it providing error but i cant able to sort this problem

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you. You have an exception if there is no value with key you pass to get method.

So you can use [optJSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optJSONArray%28java.lang.String%29) to get array, and opt (like optString, optJSONObject, etc.) methods to get other values. These methods does not throw exception, they just returns null if there are no values with key you passed.

You getting your exception because json array length is less than 10  so it is better to use
method [length()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#length%28%29) of JSONArray object instead of number 10 in for.

Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    objItem = new QuestionsObject();

    objItem.setDbcsFacebookProfile(objJson.optString(dbcsFacebookProfile));

    objItem.setAvatar_img(objJson.optString(Avatar_image));

    objItem.setVotebar(objJson.optString(percentagenumber));

    objItem.setProfile_picture_value(objJson.optString(PROFILE_PIC_VALUE));

    objItem.setId(objJson.optString(ID));
    objItem.setTitle(objJson.optString(TITLE));
    objItem.setNick_name(objJson.optString(NICKNAME));
    objItem.setQues_type(objJson.optString(QUESTIONTYPE));
    objItem.setCategories(objJson.getString(CATEGORIES));
    objItem.setSubcatid(objJson.getString(SUBCATID));
    objItem.setTotal_vote(objJson.getString(TV));

    arrayOfList.add(objItem);
}
```

Comment: Post your log cat too please. It will be easier to understand if I will see stack trace of the error.

Comment: Y i changed that but the problem is in second response some parameters are missing so only problem arise,if you sort out that issue,it will be so needfull

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Your doing all correct except following three

```
objItem.setCategories(objJson.getString(CATEGORIES));
objItem.setSubcatid(objJson.getString(SUBCATID));
objItem.setTotal_vote(objJson.getString(TV));
```

Change it `getString` as `optString`

```
objItem.setCategories(objJson.optString(CATEGORIES));
objItem.setSubcatid(objJson.optString(SUBCATID));
objItem.setTotal_vote(objJson.optString(TV));
```

Or

```
if(objJson.has(CATEGORIES))
   objItem.setCategories(objJson.getString(CATEGORIES));

if(objJson.has(SUBCATID))
   objItem.setSubcatid(objJson.getString(SUBCATID));

if(objJson.has(TV))
   objItem.setTotal_vote(objJson.getString(TV));
```

**EDIT**

Change your for as like below you have specify that **10** but jsonArray length is only 7 that's error Index out of range

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
```

Comment: No if i try with getstring then also the same problem i'm facing

Comment: @user3282586 use `optString` or use my second edit option for all getString and optString.

Comment: @user3282586 chack my edit.. **change your for loop** like `for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {`

Answer (score 0):

Please update you code by this for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    objItem = new QuestionsObject(); 
    objItem.setDbcsFacebookProfile(objJson.optString(dbcsFacebookProfile));
    objItem.setAvatar_img(objJson.optString(Avatar_image));   
    objItem.setVotebar(objJson.optString(percentagenumber));   
    objItem.setProfile_picture_value(objJson.optString(PROFILE_PIC_VALUE));   
    objItem.setId(objJson.optString(ID));
    objItem.setTitle(objJson.optString(TITLE));
    objItem.setNick_name(objJson.optString(NICKNAME));
    objItem.setQues_type(objJson.optString(QUESTIONTYPE));
    objItem.setCategories(objJson.getString(CATEGORIES));
    objItem.setSubcatid(objJson.getString(SUBCATID));   
    if(objJson.has(TV)){       
        objItem.setTotal_vote(objJson.getString(TV));      
    }
    arrayOfList.add(objItem);
}
```